# Scrapy FormRequest return 400 error code

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to scrapy following website in which the pagination is though AJAX request. 
http://studiegids.uva.nl/xmlpages/page/2014-2015/zoek-vak

I am sending FormRequest to access the different pages, however I am getting following error. 
Retrying http://studiegids.uva.nl/xmlpages/plspub/uva_search.courses_pls> (failed 1 times): 400 Bad Request

Not able to understand what is wrong? Following is the code.

```
class Spider(BaseSpider):
name = "zoek"
allowed_domains = ["studiegids.uva.nl"]
start_urls = ["http://studiegids.uva.nl/xmlpages/page/2014-2015/zoek-vak"]

def parse(self, response):
    base_url = "http://studiegids.uva.nl/xmlpages/page/2014-2015/zoek-vak"
    for i in range(1, 10):
        data = {'p_fetch_size': unicode(20),
                'p_page:': unicode(i),
                'p_searchpagetype': u'courses',
                'p_site_lang': u'nl',
                'p_strip': u'/2014-2015',
                'p_ctxparam': u'/xmlpages/page/2014-2015/',
                'p_rsrcpath':u'/xmlpages/resources/TXP/studiegidswebsite/'}

        yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                        formdata=data,
                                        callback=self.fetch_details,
                                        dont_click=True)

        # yield FormRequest(base_url,
        #                   formdata=data,
        #                   callback=self.fetch_details)

def fetch_details(self, response):
    # print response.body
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = ZoekItem()
    Studiegidsnummer = hxs.select("//div[@class=item-info']//tr[1]/td[2]/p/text()")
    Studielast = hxs.select("//div[@class=item-info']//tr[2]/td[2]/p/text()")
    Voertaal = hxs.select("//div[@class=item-info']//tr[3]/td[2]/p/text()")
    Ingangseis = hxs.select("//div[@class=item-info']//tr[4]/td[2]/p/text()")
    Studiejaar = hxs.select("//div[@class=item-info']//tr[5]/td[2]/p/text()")
    Onderwijsinstituut = hxs.select("//div[@class=item-info']//tr[6]/td[2]/p/text()")


    for i in range(20):
        item['Studiegidsnummer'] = Studiegidsnummer
        item['Studielast'] = Studielast
        item['Voertaal'] = Voertaal
        yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also check headers using firebug.

Answer (score 0):

`400 Bad Request` usually means that your request does not fully match the expected request format. Common causes include missing or invalid cookies,  headers or parameters.

On your web browser, open the Network tab of the Developer Tools and trigger the request. When you see the request in the Network tab, inspect it fully (parameters, headers, etc.). Try to match such a request in your code.